# Some instances of a ReactJS component won't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-functional-component

I'm developing a VOD app for TV and I'm having an issue with updating an element inside of a slide component. Basically, when a costumer focuses on any of the slides, it calls on a method that stores it's ID on state and then, one of their children checks if the stored state equals the selected item state and if so, it renders. On focusout, it sets the state to null.
The weird thing is in most instances of the component this works, but some of them (and always the same instances) won't update.

PSEUDOCODE:

```
handleFocus(id){setFocused(id)} // Sets the id to state
handlefocusout(){setFocused(null)} // resets state
{isFocused === item.id && <div/>} // checks if state === id and renders
```

Me and my TL are at a loss as of why it won't work on some of the instances, and unless I'm mistaken, it's always on the same ones. Mind you, the instances' content come all from the same JSON response and are all the same in content (hence instance).

Comment: What are the result of debugging this? As in, logging variables inside your function handlers, etc. to narrow down what exactly the cause is? If you look at the raw slide data, do the failing ones all have something in common?

Comment: Nothing came out of them. They ALL are exactly the same. But I figured out adding the EventHandler was the problem. I actually just fixed it removing the EventListener and adding React's `onFocus`, `onMouseOver` events and it worked great.

Comment: Are you saying you were using addEventListener to add event handlers directly to DOM elements?

Comment: When you put it like that...
I have a few EventListeners set this way when they have to listen throughout the entire app (Exit Button on remote control, for instance)

Comment: I'm not surprised that didn't work; you're not supposed to do that. Only add event listeners to window or document but not to stuff rendered by React

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found out why the EventListener wouldn't trigger properly, but I finally removed it and added React's event handlers to the element and it started working.